# tracking commits in a Git branch

Tags: git, version-control

In a quest to understand Git branches, I've come across the following, [cited from this page - toward the bottom](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell),

> Because a branch in Git is actually a simple file that contains the 40 character SHA-1 checksum of the commit it points to, branches are cheap to create and destroy.

In a Git repo of one of my projects, when I open this file `.git\refs\heads\master`, the only thing in that file is a 40 character SHA-1, which verifies the above statement.

Now this next part, [cited from this page - definition for "branch"](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary), is what I have a question about -

> A "branch" is a line of development. The most recent commit on a branch is referred to as the tip of that branch. The tip of the branch is referenced by a branch head, which moves forward as additional development is done on the branch.

Say there are 12 commits within a branch called `feature-400`.  Are they chained together by each commit keeping track of its parent or does the branch itself somehow track this history?

Comment: Note that people use the word *branch* in an ambiguous manner, when working with Git. See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) (This is a side remark; [Marcus Müller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71385497/1256452) is correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former, i.e., parent tracking.